# How to get these Python statements in the correct order?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the code:

```
age = input("How Old Are You?")
gender = str(input("What is your gender (Please no caps)"))

if isinstance(age,int):
    age = int(age)
else:
    print("Enter a valid age")

age = int(age)

if gender == "male":
    if age < 30:
        print("Watch Captain America")
    elif age > 30:
        print("Watch Johnny English")
    else:
        print("Watch Iron Man")
elif gender == "female":
    if age < 30:
        print("Watch Frozen")
    elif age > 30:
        print("Watch Cinderella")
    else:
        print("Watch Fox and the Hound")
else:
    print("Enter a Valid Gender")
```

This program recommends a movie for you to watch, based on age and gender.

I am not sure what the error is. This is written in Python 3.5.1 and does not work on Python 2.x.

## Edit

Sorry, I did not explain it well enough, what I am trying to do is that if the User enters a character, then there is no error message, but they are prompted to try again.

That is the use of this block, which I cannot work out:

```
if isinstance(age,int):
    age = int(age)
else:
    print("Enter a valid age")
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Sorry, the psuedo code was from school so I can't change the Outputs, otherwise I would get shouted at

Comment: I'm amused by the kind request in the prompt for no caps,  is that really part of your school's pseudocode?

Comment: `age = int(age)` age _is_ casted to int in program.

Comment: @Lafexlos Not before the check with `isinstance`.

Comment: no, @Donkey Kong, that was just me

Comment: @TheEngineer You could use `.lower()` on your input string and then accept caps, if you'd like. Give your program some extra flair ;)

Comment: @DonkeyKong If I'm not missing something, there are two int casts in code. One of them is  outside of `if`. If this is python 3, this will print "Enter a valid age" then casts to int anyway.

Comment: What is the "error" you talking about? Are you getting wrong output? no output at all? What is your input? Please be specific.

Comment: @Lafexlos Well yes. But it shouldn't print that, is my point.

Comment: [Not necessarily in the right order](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=-zHBN45fbo8)?

Comment: minus one to your school for the sexism and apparent threats to shout at you if you change the outputs.

Comment: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) After the edit, I assume, this is what you want.

Comment: I was over-exaggerating, they wouldn't shout at me, I live in a country where even shouting at a child (if you're not their parent) can get you jail time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This block is unnecessary and confusing:

```
if isinstance(age,int):
    age = int(age)
else:
    print("Enter a valid age")
```

At the point of you receiving `age`, it is *always* going to be a string, so this will *always* print "Enter a valid age".

What you want to do is the cast to `int` when you get the input.  You can also remove the redundant cast to `str` on your other input since they default to string.

```
age = int(input("How Old Are You?"))
gender = input("What is your gender (Please no caps)")
```

Otherwise, from what I can tell your program works fine (in spite of the "error" message).

Comment: @vaultah:  **This isn't Python 2.**

Comment: @vaultah I think OP's "this doesn't work in Python 2" was just to help out anyone trying to help in Python 2, not a desire to have it work in Python 2 :P

Comment: @Makoto: it seems that I misinterpreted the question then. **Thank you for being so patient.**